# Crear una línea en un csv desde varias líneas de otro archivo

Tags: python, csv

tengo un fichero de texto de entrada con la siguiente estructura:

```
Begin Campo1
    Propiedad1
    Propiedad2
    PropiedadA
    PropiedadB
Begin Campo2
    Propiedad1
    PropiedadA
Begin Campo3
    Propiedad1
Begin Campo4
Begin Campo5
    Propiedad1
    PropiedadA
Begin Campo6
    Propiedad1
    Propiedad2
    Propiedad3
    PropiedadA
    PropiedadB
```

Lo que necesito hacer es extraer las líneas que contengan Begin, PropiedadA y PropiedadB y guardarlas en un csv seguidas por línea, es decir Begin, PropiedadA, PropiedadB. La dificultad que me estoy tropezando es que no todos los campos Begin tienen PropiedadA o PropiedadB y no siempre están en la misma línea respecto de Begin.

El código con el que estoy trabajando es éste:

```
import csv
    
f = open ('fichero.txt')

linea = f.readline()

with open('Campos Extraidos.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            
    fieldnames = ['Begin', 'PropiedadA', 'PropiedadB']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
    writer.writeheader()
       
    while linea:
        encontrado = linea.find("Begin ")
        encontradoA = linea.find("PropiedadA")
        encontradoB = linea.find("PropiedadB")
        
        if encontradoA  > 0:
            print(linea, end='')
            propiedadA = linea
        else:
            propiedadA = ''

        if encontradoB > 0:
            print(linea, end='')
            propiedadB = linea
        else:
            propiedadB = ''

        if  encontrado > 0:
            print (linea.replace('Begin ', ''), end='')
            begin = linea.replace('Begin ', '')
        else:
            begin = ''
            

        if begin != '' or propiedadA != '' or propiedadB != '':    
            resultado = ({'Begin': begin, 'PropiedadA ': propiedadA , 'PropiedadB' : propiedadB})
            writer.writerow(resultado)

        linea = f.readline()

f.close()
exit
```

Con él consigo extraer las líneas, pero el problema es que no me las guarda enteras, debería ser:

```
Campo1 PropiedadA PropiedadB
Campo2 PropiedadA
Campo3
Campo4
Campo5 PropiedadA
Campo6 PropiedadA PropiedadB
```

Y lo que obtengo es

```
Campo1 
       PropiedadA 
       PropiedadB
Campo2 
       PropiedadA
Campo3
Campo4
Campo5 
       PropiedadA
Campo6 
       PropiedadA 
                   PropiedadB
```

He intentado hacer un bucle dentro de otro, pero no acabo de dar con cuál sería la salida del bucle para grabar la línea entera.

Gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El patrón usual en estos casos es ir acumulando los datos hasta detectar un el comienzo de un nuevo grupo, y el fin del grupo en proceso:

```
import csv

begin_text = None # Palabra que viene después de "Begin"
propiedadA = ''
propiedadB = ''

with open('Campos Extraidos.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Begin', 'PropiedadA', 'PropiedadB']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
    writer.writeheader()

    with open('fichero.txt', 'r') as f:
        for linea in f.readlines():
            linea = linea.strip()
            if linea.startswith("Begin "):
                #   Imprimir los datos acumulados
                if begin_text is not None:
                    print(f"{begin_text},{propiedadA},{propiedadB}")
                    resultado = {'Begin': begin_text, 'PropiedadA': propiedadA, 'PropiedadB': propiedadB}
                    writer.writerow(resultado)

                _, begin_text = linea.split()
                propiedadA = propiedadB = ''
            elif linea == "PropiedadA":
                propiedadA = linea
            elif linea == "PropiedadB":
                propiedadB = linea
```

Por tanto, el ciclo principal va leyendo la información de entrada, y registrando los datos de interés que encuentra.

Una línea que comienza con "Begin " es el momento de revisar el material acumulado y vaciarlo al .csv.

La ejecución produce:

```
Campo1,PropiedadA,PropiedadB
Campo2,PropiedadA,
Campo3,,
Campo4,,
Campo5,PropiedadA,

Process finished with exit code 0
```

El archivo queda

```
rvaldes@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ more Campos\ Extraidos.csv 
Begin;PropiedadA;PropiedadB
Campo1;PropiedadA;PropiedadB
Campo2;PropiedadA;
Campo3;;
Campo4;;
Campo5;PropiedadA;
```

Comment: Espectacular respuesta, bien explicada, y ahí es donde estaba fallando yo, en el algoritmo. Muchísimas gracias por tu inestimable ayuda.